# What is the reason of memory gap in hard drives?

Tags: windows, linux, administration

I want to know that what is the exact reason behind memory difference in our hard drives or pen drives .

As when we say , We have a pen drive of 4GB but actual usable space is 3.7GB . What happens to the rest of memory? Are the manufacturing companies stealing these memory spaces from us or there is any technical reason behind this?

Thanks,

Nitesh Kumar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175176/advertised-disk-space-vs-actual-disk-space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use decimal prefixes, you're using binary prefixes. This gives a discrepancy of approximately 2.4% per prefix magnitude.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams !!!